# jQuery animation queue with common easing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have jQuery animations which queued up for a single element:

```
var el = $('.elem');

el.animate({
        width: 120
    },
    600,
    'easeInOutQuint'
).animate({
        width: 90
    },
    300,
    'easeInOutQuint'
).animate({
        width: 100
    },
    100,
    'easeInOutQuint'
);
```

The 3 animation counts as 1 main animation, just chained. It takes 1000ms to run and I would like to use in my example for the first animation the first 60% of the easing, then the easing next 30% used in the second animation and it finished with the last 10% of the easing.

Is there any way to make the easing as a global value for these queued animations?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you wish to avoid typing the easing every time? You can just store it in a variable and use that. If that is not correct, what do you want to accomplish?

Comment: Please check my comment on @sza answer, that should clear this question.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question correctly, maybe you can wrap the logic in a function so you can pass in the duration and reuse the chained animation like this:

```
var el = $('.elem');

var ease = function(elem, duration) {
    elem
    .animate({width: 120}, 0.6 * duration, 'easeInOutQuint')
    .animate({width:  90}, 0.3 * duration, 'easeInOutQuint')
    .animate({width: 100}, 0.1 * duration, 'easeInOutQuint');
}

ease(el, 1000);
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I did not understand the question at all. But good call. +1 for nice solution!

Comment: Yeah like this one for sure!

Comment: Here is your code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sAJDf/ every tree part of the animation use the same easing, but not a common easing. Your example use http://easings.net/#easeInOutQuint (see easing diagram) this animation per instance of your animations. So every 3 animation in and out part is slow and that breaks the dynamics of the animation group. I need a global easing for this three animation. It would be something like, first animation easeInQuint, second is a linear with shorter duration and then an easeOutQuint. Do you see the different? http://jsfiddle.net/jMAjw/

Answer (score 2):

Another method to make it as plugin. With [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h4pBb/)

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.ease = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            style: "swing",
            duration : 1000
        }, options );

        return this.each(function(){
            $(this)
            .animate({width: 120}, 0.6 * settings.duration, settings.style)
            .animate({width:  90}, 0.3 * settings.duration, settings.style)
            .animate({width: 100}, 0.1 * settings.duration, settings.style);
        }); 
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

usage 
html : `<span>This is test line to to work on animate plugin ease</span>`
js : `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').ease()
});`

can give inputs too as `$(element).ease({duration:2000});`

Comment: Please check my comment on @sza answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
The simplest way to do this is keep it nested like:

$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    width: "140px"

  }, 5000, "", function() {
       $( "#note" ).animate({
          width: "100px"    
             }, 4000, "", function() {   
                $("#note2").animate({
                    width: "60px"

                    }, 2000, "", function() {    
               }) 
       })
  })
});
```

Comment: Please check my comment on @sza answer.